# Cannot build app with Gradle with flavors and com.google.gms.google-services plugin

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-productflavors, android-min-sdk

When i try to compile my app with flavors based on minSdk i receive an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processCurrentDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
> >     available at
> >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
> >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.0.

I pasted example from [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html) and it's not working.

project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pl.net.szafraniec.testApp'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        legacy {
            minSdkVersion 9
            versionCode 901  // Min API level 9, v01
        }
        current {
            minSdkVersion 14
            versionCode 1401  // Min API level 14, v01
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    legacyCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    currentCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.f2prateek.ln:ln:1.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: is any of the dependencies (e.g. 'com.f2prateek.ln:ln:1.1.1') using a different version?

Comment: download json file and paste into app folder

Comment: @KarthikSridharan I have json file already in app folder.

Comment: @Henry nope, without ln problem still exists.

Comment: Link to my project at current state https://github.com/mateusz-szafraniec/TestApp/tree/testing

Comment: @msc3 Did you find a solution?

Comment: @paul nope, but i abandonned branch <14

Answer (score 0):

One [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834042/version-conflict-updating-to-play-services-9-4-0-android-studio-2-2) for this issue is to put the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line below your dependencies block which allows the plugin to determine what version of Play services you are using. Since you've already done that, try to download `Google Support Repository`. You can find it in `Tools`  -> `Android` -> `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools`.

You may also check the answers in this related SO post: [Google Play Services GCM 9.2.0 asks to "update" back to 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127053/google-play-services-gcm-9-2-0-asks-to-update-back-to-9-0-0)

Comment: I have latest `Google Support Repository` already. Problem still exists...