# com.android.support:appcompat-v7 vs com.google.android.gms:play-services

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-mapview

In my project I want use mapview in navigation draw activity but
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.3 and com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1   in my project gradle are against eachother.
Which version is capable?

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".....my project name......."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`line at the **bottom** of your `app/build.gradle file`.

As discussed in [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin), as part of enabling Google APIs or Firebase services in your Android application you may have to add the `google-services` plugin to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, the `google-services` plugin has two main functions:

> 1. Process the `google-services.json` file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code.
> 2. Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires that the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line be at the **bottom** of your `app/build.gradle` file so that no dependency collisions are introduced. You can see the result of this step by running `./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

See this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834042/version-conflict-updating-to-play-services-9-4-0-android-studio-2-2) and this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions) for additional insights

Comment: This is my change but it dosnt work   

dependencies {
.....
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Error:(33, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Hiihi\Desktop\Mynav\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

its error.

Comment: Have you also added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in your project's `build.gradle`?

Comment: i do this no:--->

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}

Comment: this is error---->

Error:(32, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'H12' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'H12' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>